# Method getCallbackTokenAsync returns the same token in Outlook 2013

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We are currently developing an Office365 Add-In for Outlook 2013. The purpose of the add-in is to create Jira issues from emails, plus custom business logic. For getting information about an email we are using the token returned by method "getCallbackTokenAsync" and the email id. Everything is working perfect on web application but on Desktop Outlook 2013 we have problems.
The problems consists in that the "getCallbackTokenAsync" returns the same token for different emails and this is causing an "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again." error when we calling exchange service. We need to wait for a minute or so before "getCallbackTokenAsync" return a different token.
Option to upgrade to Office 2016 is **not possible** currently. 
Is there a fix or work around for this problems?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a known bug that was fixed a while ago. Essentially Outlook is caching the token instead of requesting it each time. It was incorrectly not requesting a new token when the user selects a new item. You need to install the update described in [KB3114349](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3114349). From that article's list of fixes:

> Custom add-ins use cached access tokens instead of tokens that are retrieved from the Exchange Web Service (EWS) in Outlook 2013.
>   BUG #: 3512901 (Office15)

Comment: Thank you Jason for your response. According to the link this update applies to clients installed with a msi. My installation is Office 365 click to run. Will I be able to install the update? If not what other options I have?

Comment: Huh. I wasn't aware O365 C2R even offered 2013 :). Have you checked for updates in the product or via Windows Update? That bug was fixed over a year ago so I'd be shocked if it was not in the latest C2R distribution.

Comment: Yes they do offer Click to Run for Office 2013. The version that I have is 15.0.4771.1004, I don't know if that means something to you. Also I try to update my installation and I receive an error about my network connection and error code 416-27. Obviously this is not the case, my network connection is working. Maybe a proxy issue or something else in our infrastructure is preventing Outlook to update. I need to start checking in that direction. Than you for your response.